# loading a page in background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to load some data in a global variable in Flutter every minute.
To load the data (which is a list) to my global data, I need to open another page. But how can I open that page in the background because I do not need that page, I just want to get some data from it.

Answer (score 0):

create a different class and write a function that instantiates a list from itself
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Loading a Page is something related to UI or Presentation layer but loading your data is related to Business layer, you need to keep separate them from each other

There is a topic known as State Management, you should centralize your data providers to a separate layer and change your Presentation layer based on the State of your data

First of all take a look at [this link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple), here is an example of using Provider pattern to manage different State of your data

Then you can use some more complicated libraries like [BLOC library](https://bloclibrary.dev) for State Management

Answer (score 0):

(More of a workaround)

As I wrote [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) one option is to use [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget as a page loader.
Each "page" expand on the entire screen.

When you want to show the next "page" replace the front layer in the `stack` with `SizedBox`.

So all the elements are actually randerd at the same time but will not be visible.
For example, the video on the "second page" will start getting loaded even when the user is on the "first page" and will be ready for the user when he continues.

One way to do that is by using [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) as state management.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class PageWithLayers extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageWithLayers({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TestController c = Get.put(TestController());

    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: FutureBuilder<Widget>(
            future: Future(() async {
              await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
              return const Text('Done loading in the background');
            }),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return snapshot.requireData;
              }
              return const Text('Loading Video');
            },
          ),
        ),
        Obx(
          () => c.toShowTopLayer > 0
              ? Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  child: Center(
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: c.removeTopLayer,
                      child: const Text('Next'),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : const SizedBox(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TestController extends GetxController {
  var toShowTopLayer = 1.obs;

  removeTopLayer() => toShowTopLayer--;
}
```